# Re-color multiple layers during MapBox Static Image API call?

Tags: python, api, mapbox, mapbox-api-staticimages

I'm using Mapbox's static image API to generate an image of routes I've run in the past few days.  Due to URL character limits, I'm going the tileset route: each run is uploaded as a Tileset Source, I have a recipe that blends them all, and then I publish a single Tileset with many layers.

I'd like to be able to call the static image API and tell it (eg) make layer_01 "red" and [layer_02, layer_03] "grey".  Customizing the color is possible with addLayer, but I can't figure out how to call multiple layers from the same tileset.  Is this possible?

If not, do I need to add all layers to a custom Style, and republish it with new colors before every call?  That seems incredibly cumbersome to have to constantly rebuild styles.

Comment: Are you uploading all of your runs as distinct tilesets or updating a single tileset every time you add a new run?

Comment: I have five runs, each uploaded as a tileset source.  The five tileset sources are combined into a single tileset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to give specific advice without seeing your style or the structure of your tilesets.

However, based on your description of your setup, I believe you can accomplish your goal of "re-coloring routes" by generating the route style layer on the fly using the Static Image API's [`addlayer`](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#add-a-style-layer) query string parameter. `addlayer` is powerful primarily because it allows you style map data at the time of request with full use of style expressions. (Note: this recommendation assumes your route lines have some distinguishing characteristic.)

As a quick proof of concept, here is a static image request that takes the `mapbox/streets-v11` style and adds a new style layer. The layer uses the [`match`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match) expression to color roads based on their "class":

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/-122,36.99,11/300x300?before_layer=road-number-shield&addlayer={%22id%22:%22road-overlay%22,%22type%22:%22line%22,%22source%22:%22composite%22,%22source-layer%22:%22road%22,%22paint%22:{%22line-color%22:%20[%22match%22,%20[%22get%22,%20%22class%22],%20%22motorway%22,%20%22%23ff0000%22,%20%22primary%22,%20%22%23FFFF00%22,%20%22secondary%22,%20%22%23FF00FF%22,%20%22street%22,%20%22%2300FFFF%22,%20%22%23FFFFFF%22],%22line-width%22:2}}&access_token=your.tk
```

Which produces the following result:

[image: map image]

Comment: This is super helpful, I did not know about "match".  I'll post an update to the question with some more info after I test it out!